# Windows 10 blue screen won't boot, won't go into BIOS either

Tags: windows, bluescreenview

Hi some one please help me, I have a dell vostro 14 5459 windows laptop and it crashed now I can't get in to the bios it doesn't boot it goes to repair/restore window and sometimes to a blues screen with different stop codes like: IRQL less or not equal, system pte misuse, memory management error...

Comment: You probably need to the Dell Diagnostics App on a bootable USB Key.  I am not sure from the above if it will boot to a USB Key or not. If it does, run the diagnostics.  You likely need to get the machine serviced at a local repair shop.

Comment: Use the following link and follow instructions under "from black or blank screen" to boot to Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) and do the troubleshooting steps like startup repair. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234

Comment: Also add more details on what  you did that caused the issue.

Comment: Try to boot from a live USB, e.g., Linux or Win R E. If that works, and you can use it to access your HD drive and see all the files, then you know it's an issue with Windows OS, which can be fixed by reinstalling it. If the boot from USB works,  but you *cannot* access  the HDD, the HDD is likely failing. If you cannot boot from USB, it's hardware issues, other than HDD.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 10 and can get into the WinRE (Windows Recovery Environment), that's good. Get a live USB of Windows 10 prepared. Access the command prompt and route it to the mounted live USB. Use `d:` (or whatever the drive letter might be). Once you're in there, type `run setup.exe`. This should take you to the Windows 10 setup process. Follow the instructions to reinstall Windows.